# Probability of Specific Die Roll with Indeterminate Number of Rolls

Tags: probability, dice, inclusion-exclusion

I have a problem I'm working through.

You roll a fair die *m* times.  What is the probability $P(x)$ that exactly *j* of the rolls are $>4$ (that is, 5 or 6)?

Through seeing some similar problems, I believe that there is a solution involving inclusion-exclusion.  Roughly speaking take the possibility of outcomes and subtract the two specific ones.

Following that line of thinking, I think it should look something like this, but feel I shouldn't be doing $6 \choose 4$ each time, or maybe this result should be subtracted form 1 for the two specific clauses I'm looking for:
$6 \choose 4$$6^m$$-$$ 6 \choose 4$$5^m$$+$$6 \choose 4$$4^m$$-$$6 \choose 4$$3^m$$+$$6 \choose 4$$2^m$$-$$6 \choose 4$$1^m$$+$$6 \choose 4$$0^m$

What am I doing wrong here and is this in fact an application of inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: Since each trial is the same, you should use the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  The Inclusion-Exclusion Principle is not required here.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ = number of rolls > 4. $X\sim$ Bin$(m,\frac{1}{3})$

Using the pdf of a binomial random variable, we have:
$$
P(X=j)=p_X(j)=\binom{m}{j}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^j\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{m-j}
$$

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function

Comment: Got it, thank you @Carter Karl Falkenberg